# (Datatables.net + Angular) button on each row function doesn't work, but it works on button's array. So any is there any helps?

Tags: angular, datatables, angular-material, datatables-1.10

I'm trying to put action on each row of datatables in a column but idk why its didn't work, already pull many of tricks but still not work, so I'm giving up and end up trying to ask in here :) thanks you 
source: datatables.net, im using this for make all of my tables data also angular as my frontent

This is my ts code

```
export class DatatableComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {}

check() {
    console.log('helloworld');
}


this.dtOptions = {
      ajax: {
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/demoserver',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
      },
      columns: [
        {
          title: 'ID',
          data: 'ID',
        },
        //*does'nt works 
        {
          title: 'Option',
          data: null,
          defaultContent: '<button>Details</button>',
          action: () => {
            this.check();
        },
        //*
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
      buttons: [
        { extend: 'excel', text: 'Export' },
        {
          text: '<i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i>',
          action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
            dt.ajax.reload();
          },
        },
        //*works
        {
          text: 'Add',
          action: () => {
            this.cek();
          },
        //*
        },  
      ],
    };

  },
}
```

and this is my html code

```
<table
  datatable
  [dtOptions]="dtOptions"
  class="mc row-border hover"
  style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px;"
>
  <button mat-button (click)="openDialog()">Details</button>//imtrying to put this button into that columns but too sad, even check with log does'nt work on it.
</table>
```

Comment: any error comes up if you put button into columns?

Comment: no errors, just nothing happen. there is no anything on console, if we press the button inside the datatables.